# Options for growing indoors

Tags: houseplants, indoors

I made the bad decision to move to an apartment (central Florida) governed by hoa who prohibits plants on the balcony. I am looking at options what I can grow and how. I have basil, oregano, thyme, chives starting, medium rosemary plant and old chilli pepper and a starting a small pot tomato.

I think of a few options (I am willing to adjust what i am growing but the rosemary tree has to stay), 1) have some soil vertical planter close to the window, 2) a soil-less planter next to the window (both with possible added lights), or 3) get a grow tent. I have no experience with grow tents, growing lights or vertical planters or soil-less growing. I have a lot of experience with standard backyard garden in pots with soil, growing tomatoes, peppers, herbs etc. My budget is at most $200.

Anyone with suggestion and personal experience how to grow inside an apartment or even that it is not really feasible and i have to get rid of the plants.

Comment: What direction does your balcony face?

Comment: Maybe its time to consider growing indoor plants instead (Hoyas?  Orchids?).    A growing tent for tomatos could work, but with a budget of $200 you may bulk at the price of electricity - even LED grow lights use a fair amount of electricity.

Comment: Its a little outside your budget - but have a look at https://vegepod.com/collections/all-products/products/kitchen-garden-white-pre-order-now-for-feb-15th-ship-date for inspiration.  I think they are quite cool.  (They are fairly small, so good fer herbs indoors, not so much chili peppers/tomatos).   Also nothing to say you can't make your own for less $$$

Comment: The thing with lighing is that our eyes trick us - on a sunny day you will get more then 100k lux outdoors, but less then 1k lux in a brightly lit room.  This means you will want to have your grow lights as close to the plants as possible as lux drops off on the square of the distance from memory.   You also should work out if you and your chosen plants can accept the purple glow of lights which cut out the green spectrum to save $$$

Comment: @Jurp The balcony is towards the east on the second floor with one more balcony above.

Comment: @davidgo My main growing plants are edibles. When I was renting a house, I added flowers to attract bees and others. But I have not much motivation to grow purely ornamentals without any culinaries. You are right about the light intensity dropping as distance squared. What I am also quite worried is the air quality and the general design of watering. The system that you posted seems quite expensive given the size.

Comment: Inexpensive plastic tents are ugly. Just saying. Could you mask the plants on the balcony behind wicker chairs, ornaments, banners, macrame, flamingoes, parasols, "art"?

Comment: @YosefBaskin I like this general idea, if the HOA tinpot dictators will allow OP to do that. Maybe selling it as a "wind screen" for the balcony, hung with zip-ties from the railing? It would probably have to be no higher than the railing, if it's allowed. OP can't build a free-standing structure closer to the building wall because the balcony won't get much sun there (east-facing, with no overhead light that close to the building). OP - would your HOA allow an opaque "wind screen" on all three sides of the balcony?

Comment: I was picturing 2 translucent, not opaque, lounge chairs on their side - Oh, the wind musta knocked 'em over! - forming a U-shaped camouflage.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Ah. The HOA will just expect him to pick the chairs up and tie them down so that they "don't blow over" again. I think an opaque screen is the only real solution here, unless OP has a second, unused, bedroom in the apartment.

Comment: @atapaka  Random thought - have you considered looking for a community garden in your area?

Answer (score 1):

As far as fruiting plants indoors go, I recommend ground cherries (the Aunt Molly's, Goldie, and Ammon Martin's types). They fruit pretty easily indoors. I've never actually tried growing them indoors beyond the seed-starting stage, but when I started them super early, they did fruit indoors (on south window light) before the transplant, without trouble. Tomatillos, on the other hand, don't fruit as easily indoors as ground cherries (some people call ground cherries tomatillos, so don't be confused by that).

Watch out for things like spider mites. They didn't bother mine indoors, but they sure did outdoors (peppers seemed the reverse; they seemed to bother them indoors but not outdoors).

For herbs/greens, I might recommend trying green onions / scallions (for the greens; not for the bulbs). Actually grow them in soil from seed (not in water from grocery store scallions like they say to do online; they do actually need nutrients, and growing grocery store produce can be illegal in some cases).

As a herb, you might also try a makrut lime (Citrus hystrix). The leaves can be used in cooking. I haven't grown a makrut lime tree, but I have grown citrus trees.

A lot of people recommend basil and mint for indoors, but I don't personally.

For houseplants, I recommend these:

- Spider plants (Chlorophytum comosum; these plants are very rewarding, I think; they make the air smell good if they get enough sun, water, and growth; the plants grow a lot more vigorously with more sun, but people tell you to avoid that so the tips don't burn; however, it's not the end of the world if the tips burn; you can trim the tips off and they'll grow new leaves; they also grow more spiderettes with more sun, and the plants develop more growth points in the soil more frequently; they grow bigger in bigger pots, if they have enough sun; however, people often like to put them in hanging baskets or lower light where they don't grow to their full growth potential)
- Golden pothos (these are lot more rewarding if they're not in a small container, because they grow faster and don't get stunted as easily; they don't need a lot of light to do well, but don't neglect to water them when they need it or they may lose leaves)
- Thanksgiving cactuses
- Stapelia (don't get one of the more difficult species of Stapelia to keep as a houseplant; these are attractive cactus-like plants that grow cool flowers; they're not cacti, though; my grandma had one in an eastern windowsill, and everyone loved it; it never had the smell people talk about, as far as I know, though, but it had big flowers)
- English ivy (most people grow this outdoors, but it makes a good houseplant; make sure your plant is disease-free, and ideally not taken as a cutting from an outdoor plant, since it might have diseases and/or pests)
- Tradescantia (the solid green vining type is really cool for a houseplant; to get it to live for a long time without taking new cuttings, you may need to do some research)
- Fittonia
- Geraniums (I forgot which genus I mean, but some plants known as Geraniums both flower nicely and make decent houseplants if you have a reasonable amount of sun; the leaves smell good, almost like carrots.)
- Arrowhead plant
- Philodendron hederaceum (Heartleaf Philodendron; these are kind of like a golden pothos with smaller, but solid-green leaves, and faster growth, with sheaths)

One thing you really need to remember is that the smaller your pot is, the faster the soil will dry out, and the more drought-stress a plant will experience if it does dry out. It's a lot easier to kill a plant in a small pot because the drought does more damage. A lot of people will warn you not to make the pot too large for the plant, but they won't tell you it makes plants more finnicky and makes them so they don't grow as big; you can always plant multiple cuttings in a larger pot to compensate for smaller plant size, if you want the benefits of a larger pot without having it be too big.

Problems with pots that are *too* big include these:

- Uneven watering (if the plant has been freshly transplanted, it needs frequent moisture where the roots are—not simply in the pot; for new plants you'll probably need to do frequent light waterings, such as with a thin spout)
- Some plants, such as snake plants, are said to prefer a tighter pot (perhaps to help them grow more evenly and upright); snake plants are popular, but I didn't mention them above since I consider the ones I did mention above easier to grow.

Some houseplants you might consider that I haven't grown are these:

- Chinese Evergreen
- Cast-iron plant

Some plants you might try if you're adventurous, but I don't really recommend as easy plants include these:

- African violets
- Aloes
- Snake plants
- Orchids

If you want a big plant, you might try an umbrella tree or a rubber fig, but there are special things to know about with caring for them:

Rubber figs seem to like frequent waterings, but not lots at once; they don't like frequent changes in their light levels; don't move it to a new location often; let it adjust to each location before moving it again, and ideally don't move it at all. You might need to stake them.

Umbrella trees might be more touchy about nitrogen fertilizer, but are otherwise easy to care for (you might need to stake them).

Many kinds of cacti make good houseplants (I don't know the binomial names for all of them), but if they have thorns you might get them in you on mysterious occasions for no apparent reason. I had a cool big cactus once, but we had to get rid of it, because it had large thorns (about 1.5" long) that seemed dangerous (I woke up with one in my abdomen one time). It was a great plant, though. I think it was some kind of prickly pear.

Answer (score 0):

I have grown kitchen herbs indoors in open pots before, and it worked OK.  It took more fussing from me for less harvest from them than when I was able to grow outdoors, and I found myself in an escalating effort to please them that was taking me towards a full on grow tent.  My main problem was lack of light indoors, but you are in Florida, so maybe it will work better for you.

Later on, I was given a commercial hydroponic 'garden' as a gift.  It is a reservoir of water and fertilizer, and a bank of LED lights.  I am responsible for keeping the water topped up, adding nutrients on the prescribed schedule, and keeping it plugged in.  It's honestly quite convenient.

I have grown dill, thyme, oregano, basil, peppers, and tomatoes in mine.  One consideration is that you generally want the plants to be at the same height, so it can be challenging to keep a basil plant in check next to a slower growing pepper plant.

A common strategy with these gardens is to try to convince you your garden can only grow their 'seed pods', which are kind of expensive.  There is nothing special about these 'pods', they are seeds in growth medium.  There are lots of guides online to making your own.  Cost of ownership is reasonable.

From what you have said, I think growing them in pots might work for you.  But if you are going to start supplementing their light, I would suggest going straight for a commercial hydroponic setup.  They don't cost much more than a decent light alone.  I see a comment suggesting a ~$200 setup, that's pretty steep.  Mine was ~$100 new, and I'm seeing some online for ~$40 that look alright to me.  "Hydroponic herb garden" was my google search.

Comment: In all honestly I resented the hydroponic garden when I received it.  I really like it now, fresh dill and basil 100% of the time.